# How to change Sublime Text temp file location?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Sublime Text stores the temp file alongside the file under edit as `._foo.txt`. How to change it's location and/or naming scheme? In could do it in say `vim` with `set dir=/var/tmp`, is there anything similar in Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the setting is

```
"atomic_save": false
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634684/what-is-sublime-text-doing-when-i-save-a-file) (which really ought to be on SU, but I don't have the super cow powers to do that).